# jquery user input to upper case not work on some case

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, uppercase

I using Jquery to cover user input to upper case on real time. But I received some of the data is not in upper case about 2%. May I know what possible to cause this?

```
//convert all lower case to upper case
$("input, textarea").not("[data-controlname='txtCompanyEmailAddress'] input," +
                    "[data-controlname='KeyAccEmailaddress'] input," +
                    "[data-controlname='AccDeptEmailaddress'] input," +
                    "[data-controlname='CompanyEmail'] input," +
                    "[data-controlname='CompanyURL'] input," +
                    "[data-controlname='txtInternalComment'] textarea," +
                    "[data-controlname='txtRejectCommentToSupplier'] textarea"
                    ).on('input', function(evt) {
          var input = $(this);
          var start = input[0].selectionStart;
          $(this).val(function (_, val) {


            return val.toUpperCase();
          });
          input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = start;
 });
```

Comment: Do you know which inputs cause the output to not be in uppercase when it should have been? Are you sure the input that fails to get converted to uppercase is not made by one of the elements you have in the `.not()` list ? Any reason you're not using the css rule `text-transform: uppercase;`?

Comment: Certainly, those input that fail coverted is not selected inside the .not().

Answer (score 0):

If there's no specific reason you're using javascript for this, an alternative is to add the following to your css:

```
.uppercase {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

And then add the `.uppercase` class to each input element that always needs to have its value in upper case.

Comment: Note that using CSS presents the text as uppercase, but doesn't change the underlying text; so when submitted to a database the text will be in the case the user entered, not the necessarily the case the user *saw* before submission.

Comment: Indeed. That would be a good valid reason to do the transformation in javascript. Then again, I would group that with any other validation code instead of updating it inline each time there's input.

Comment: Agreed, but it's one of those caveats that's worth mentioning in the answer.